# Download exact email data using bounced from API call

Tags: api

How can I get all the data from the bounced emails using API call.

When I use my API call to get data, I only retrieve first 500 records using curl, Can it be possible to get all the data and download in a file.

The command which I am using is as below ... I tried to increase limit of the API call with 501 below was the error ? Can any one let me know how to resolve ?

```
curl --request GET \
--url https://${API_CALL} \
--header 'accept: application/json' \
--header 'authorization: Bearer ${AUTH_TOKEN}' \

curl --request GET \
--url https://${API_CALL}?limit=501 \
--header 'accept: application/json' \
--header 'authorization: Bearer ${AUTH_TOKEN}' \

{"errors":[{"field":"limit","message":"must be between 0 and 500"}]}
```